# Find a number not in a set

Tags: python, random, python-3.x, integer

I'm trying to find a reasonably efficient way of getting any single integer not in a set.  So for example, if I have `numbers={1, 4, 9}`, then a valid result would be `3`.  I can do it like this:

```
n = random.randint(-100, 100)
if n not in numbers:
    return n
```

But I don't want to be constrained to an arbitrary range (e.g. -100 -> 100) since I have no idea how large the set will be.  The other option would be to iterate over every integer, but that would be terribly inefficient.

Does anyone have any suggestions about a better way of doing this?

**Edit:** Because of the number of questions about exactly what I'm trying to do, I'm updating this question to explain some of the background.

What I am actually trying to achieve is a mapping something like this: `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 1}` where `a`, `b` and `c` are object instances.  The values in this unique for a group, so I can tell that `a` and `c` are in group 1 and `b` is in group 2.  The actual number is irrelevant, it's just a unique key for the group and doesn't relate to anything outside this structure. The actual structure is a database table whith two fields, both of which are indexed so that I can quickly find out, for example, what else is in the same group as `a`.

Now what I need the unique number for, is when I want to add a group.  This doesn't happen very often so it doesn't have to be incredibly efficient, but since the amount of data can get quite large I need to keep the number of iterations down.  I realise that there are a few simple ways of doing this to with acceptable limitations, e.g. using `randint` with a large range (e.g. 1e6), or possibly even using a database function.  But since I've been thinking about this it's become a matter of interest to find a neat solution for populating the values without hardcoded limits. Obviously memory limitations (e.g. the max size of an integer) still apply.

Comment: So does this single integer have to be between the max and min number of the set?

Comment: For efficiency, you could write a small function to calculate the min, max and count of your set. Then mathematically determine whether there are any gaps. If there's a gap, you can then check for each number from min, if there's no gap you can pick max+1 or min-1.

Comment: @jamylak: No, it can be any number. I'm basically trying to generate keys to use in a dictionary.

Comment: I'm lost in your update between your description of the database and your need to code this in python. Surely the simplest thing to do is have the second field be a foreign key to a "group" table. Any time you need a new group, you create one and the monotonically increasing row_id of the group table will handle what the number needs to be.

Comment: all that would be in the group table is a key then. But like I said, I'm interested to know how this can be solved in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> any single integer not in a set

But there's an infinite number of integer values, so there's an infinite number of integer values not in a finite set. Unless you're talking about integer within a finite range (e.g. 16 bits).

The most efficient solution will depend on the how complete the set of integers is - if it's sparse then picking a number at random is likely to return one not in the set more often. If there are few gaps, then an optimised search will be more efficient. Both of these depend on having a sorted list of the set.

Looking at the search method, it's possible to speed up the search by partitioning the data: calculate the mean M of the lowest and highest index of numbers in the list, if dataset[M]<(M-dataset[0]) then there's a gap, otherwise check if dataset[last]<(dataset[0]+last) in which case there's a gap in the second half, repeat the process for the half of the data which has a gap.

Answer (score 2):

what about `max(numbers)+1` ??

Comment: @vaisakh: Generally I wouldn't describe deploying a built in function as *creative*. Neat, yes. Elegant, perhaps. Creative, not so much.

Comment: it would require iterating of the whole set - we definitely don't need this.

Comment: @MattH: Right, but I was referring to the idea. I thought that was out-of-the box thinking. :) Quick (as in quick thinking) but dirty maybe?

Comment: @vaisakh: It's a very common pattern for assigning ID's. Even more common is keeping track of the maximum so you don't have to call max().

Comment: @LennartRegebro Sure, I know about ID's. It might be that for this problem, this seemed so straight forward (albeit inefficient) at first sight that, I was like.."how could I miss it?" :D

Comment: @RomanBodnarchuk and checking whether a randomly chosen number is in the set doesn't require iterating the set? Your answer possibly has to iterate it multiple times, until you pick a number not in the set. This iterates it *only* once. Lennart's comment is most constructive.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling `in` operator for sets is O(1).  It does **not** require iterating of the whole set.

Comment: @RomanBodnarchuk Cool. Is that part of the specification or is it just the implementation in CPython? And is that worst case included?

Comment: @ChrisWesseling Exact implementation of language primitives probably should  not be included in the spec of the language, so you may say that this is CPython impl detail.  However, implementation of Python sets as [hashtables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) seem to be a standard approach.  Yes, O(1) is a worst case both for lookup and insertion.

Answer (score 0):

```
def numnotinset(myset):
  i = min(myset)
  while True:
    i += 1
    if not i in myset:
      return i
```

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure exactly what you need

```
>>> numbers = {1, 4, 9}
>>> from itertools import count
>>> next(x for x in count() if x not in numbers)
0
```

Answer (score 0):

*No, it can be any number. I'm basically trying to generate keys to use in a dictionary.*

Sounding like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Why are you keying a dictionary with random numbers? Should you even be using a dictionary?

If you need a number index, for a dictionary, the easiest way to do it is to record the last key given out and then when you need another one, increment this number and use it.

You ignore the issue of missing indexes resulting from deletions and/or occasionally renumber.

Comment: Not exactly...  It seems there is a bit of confusion as to exactly what I mean so I'll update my question to clarify it a bit.